# org.jsonexception value of type org.jsonobject cannot be converted to jsonarray

Tags: php, android, android-json

```
exception : org.json.JSONException: Value{"id":"6","assignment":";Array","rollno":",Array","subject":"TE_DBMS_PRAC","late":";Array"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be coverted to JSONArray
```

my android code is

```
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(result);
    //arrayList.clear();
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject jsonObject=null;
        jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        rolno = jsonObject.getString("rollno");
        assign=jsonObject.getString("assignment");
        late=jsonObject.getString("late");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"return",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(rolno.contains(rollno.getText().toString()))
        {
            String[] rrno = rolno.split(",");
            String[] assignm=assign.split(";");
            String[] lates=late.split(";");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"roll on are"+rrno[1]+"and assign are"+assignm[1],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            for(int j=0;j<rrno.length;i++){
                if(rollno.getText().toString().equals(rrno[j])){
                    String current_assign=assignm[j];
                    String current_late=lates[j];
                    String[] current_a_splitted=current_assign.split(",");

                    String[] current_l_splitted=current_late.split(",");
                    for(int k=0;k<current_a_splitted.length;k++){

                        if (Integer.parseInt(current_a_splitted[k]) == 1)
                            asg1.setChecked(true);
                        else if (Integer.parseInt(current_a_splitted[k]) == 2)
                            asg2.setChecked(true);
                        else if (Integer.parseInt(current_a_splitted[k]) == 3)
                            asg3.setChecked(true);
                        else if (Integer.parseInt(current_a_splitted[k]) == 4)
                            asg4.setChecked(true);
                        else if (Integer.parseInt(current_a_splitted[k]) == 5)
                            asg5.setChecked(true);
                        else if (Integer.parseInt(current_l_splitted[k]) == 1)
                            late1.setChecked(true);
                        else if (Integer.parseInt(current_l_splitted[k]) == 2)
                            late2.setChecked(true);
                        else if (Integer.parseInt(current_l_splitted[k]) == 3)
                            late3.setChecked(true);
                        else if (Integer.parseInt(current_l_splitted[k]) == 4)
                            late4.setChecked(true);
                        else if (Integer.parseInt(current_l_splitted[k]) == 5)
                            late5.setChecked(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    // listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception itself explains you. Your result is a `JsonObject` and not `JsonArray`

Try converting it using

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(result);
```

and handle the rest of the code accordingly